# In this Java Servlet, why do I get a 0 in my result set, from a known good sql statement

Tags: java

I am working on a fairly simple Java Servlet.  The point I am at is trying return the max of a primary key column, for a jdbc resource.

I know the resource works, as I use it heavily in other servlets.  I am have tested the sql statement in MySql Workbench, and have also tested the same statement, using the same resource within a JSP using sql jstl.  In both of these cases it returns 510867925, under the field name "Last_Record".  When I try this within my servlet, I get 0.

for debugging, I have printed a counter, the value, the field name, and the sql datatype to the page.  I have placed the counter before and after the "getLong" method to confirm that the while...next() executes correctly.

here is the servlet...

```
// Save as "binedit_entries\WEB-INF\src\mypkg\BinEdits.java"
package mypkg;
import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import javax.naming.*;

public class BinEdits extends HttpServlet {

   DataSource pool_sql;  // Database connection pool
   DataSource pool_oracle;  // Database connection pool

   @Override
   public void init( ) throws ServletException {
      try {
         // Create a JNDI Initial context to be able to lookup the DataSource
         InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
         // Lookup the DataSource, which will be backed by a pool
         //   that the application server provides.
         pool_sql = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/TrainingRequestKiosk");
         if (pool_sql == null)
            throw new ServletException("Unknown DataSource 'jdbc/TrainingRequestKiosk'");
        pool_oracle = (DataSource)ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/dcphl5");
         if (pool_oracle == null)
            throw new ServletException("Unknown DataSource 'jdbc/dcphl5'");
      } catch (NamingException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

   @Override
   public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
               throws IOException, ServletException {
      // Set the response message's MIME type
      response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
      // Allocate a output writer to write the response message into the network socket
      PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        Connection conn_sql = null;
        Connection conn_oracle = null;

        Statement stmt_lastLocalRecord = null;
        PreparedStatement stmt_getNewRecords = null;

        String uri = request.getRequestURI();
        String pageName = uri.substring(uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);
        String rootURI = uri.substring(uri.indexOf("/"),uri.lastIndexOf("/")+1);


      try { 
        String contextPath = "http://phl5-ops-dev.ant.amazon.com:8080" + rootURI;
        String SiteID = "PHL5";
        int eCount = 0;
    // Get a connection from the pool
        conn_sql = pool_sql.getConnection();
        conn_oracle = pool_oracle.getConnection();


        String qry_lastLocalRecord = "select max(binedit_entry_id) AS Last_Record FROM bin_edits.BINEDIT_ENTRIES;";
        stmt_lastLocalRecord = conn_sql.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs_lastLocalRecord = stmt_lastLocalRecord.executeQuery(qry_lastLocalRecord);
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs_lastLocalRecord.getMetaData();
        long last_Record = 0;
        while (rs_lastLocalRecord.next()) {
            out.println(++eCount);
             rs_lastLocalRecord.getLong("Last_Record");
             out.println(++eCount);
        }
        //
        //Begin Web Page
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html><html><head>");
        out.println("<meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\">");
        out.println("<title>PHL5 Bin Edits</title></head>");
        out.println(last_Record);
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println(rsmd.getColumnTypeName(1));
        out.println("<br>");
        out.println(rsmd.getColumnName(1));
        out.println("</body></html>");

      } catch (SQLException ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
         out.close();
         try {
            if (conn_sql != null) conn_sql.close(); // return to pool
            if (conn_oracle != null) conn_oracle.close(); // return to pool
            if (stmt_lastLocalRecord != null) stmt_lastLocalRecord.close(); // return to pool
            if (stmt_getNewRecords != null) stmt_getNewRecords.close(); // return to pool


         } catch (SQLException ex) {
             ex.printStackTrace();
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Here is the response I get...

```
1 2 0 
BIGINT 
Last_Record
```

I would expect to see...

```
1 2 510867925
BIGINT 
Last_Record
```

Comment: You're not changing the value of last_Record. You need to get the return from `rs_lastLocalRecord.getLong("Last_Record");`

Comment: First of all just let me tell you that you should never do this in the servlet (apart from testing the concept).

Comment: Why would i not want to do this in a servlet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never assign anything to `last_Record` other than the initial 0.

I'd assume you want to do

```
last_Record = rs_lastLocalRecord.getLong("Last_Record");
```

instead of

```
rs_lastLocalRecord.getLong("Last_Record");
```

Comment: Wow, I figured I would have a "duh" moment once someone answered, but I can't believe that I, even in my limited experience, missed that one.  Thank you very much.